# Changing tabBar programmatically not working (self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = tabBarIndex:)

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uitabbarcontroller, tabbar

I'm doing a contacts app, so in one page, I need it to don't open if there's no contact, so I set a if in viewWillAppear. Everything works ALMOST great: when I select this tab, an alert tells me that there's no contact added and the tab changes, but the View doesn't
![enter image description here][1]

https://cloudup.com/cZDl8XW1aun (screenshot link)

I done a test and if I put the changing tabBar code in other place except ViewDidLoad or ViewWillAppear it works, but I don't want this.

Sorry for my bad english or if I done an idiot mistake, I'm a noob.

```
if (contacts.count == 0)
{
    UIAlertView *alerta = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Attentione" message:@"You doesn't have any contacts added" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [alerta show];

    self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1;

}
else
{
```

...
.
..
..
.
}

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to call the code to set the selected index from the viewDidLoad method:

```
- (void)viewDidload
{
  [super viewDidLoad];

  // Call from viewDidload 
  [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];
}
```